# Remote Debugger, Stepping into Library Source Code

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, shared-libraries

I am trying to remotely debug an MTP library (libmtp) on a Raspberry Pi from a Windows PC using Visual Studio 2017. I can get as far as actually compiling and stepping through code associated with the mtp-detect executable provided in the 'examples' directory of the source.

My issue is actually stepping into all of the MTP related functions within the detect.c source. I have disabled the Just My Code (JMC) option within VS 2017 with no change. I thought it would at least ask me to find the source of the function if it couldn't itself, but it doesn't seem to try to step into these functions whatsoever.

Within the project properties, I have pointed it (as far as I know) to all the directories that contain any of the source that these functions use. Surely I am missing something.

Comment: have you all source code of your library ? or some parts are in .lib ? Are you able to stepping into all of the MTP related functions in Local ?

Comment: @Landstalker I have pulled all of the source from Sourceforge.

Comment: Are you able to stepping into all of the MTP related functions in Local (without remote debugging)  to see if it comes from the configuration of the remote debugging environment ?

Comment: I am not. I have since moved to a Mac, and using VSCode. However, I hit the same dilemma. I cannot seem to step into many of the libmtp functions. I am running one of the example executables provided with the source (mtp-detect, in particular). I can't step through its code in detect.c just fine. However, it does not take me into any of the functions it calls within detect.c.